# Como mudo o caminho do meu banco de dados ao executar o programa?

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe8, object-pascal

Estou começando a programar com o *Delphi XE8* e usando *Firebird 2.5*.

Consegui implementar meu banco de dados e esta funcionando tudo certo.

O problema que estou enfrentando agora é que como eu alterno de computadores para programar (casa, faculdade, etc), tenho que mudar o caminho onde está localizado meu arquivo do banco de dados, compilar e só então consigo executar o programa.

Quero mudar a configuração do meu *TSQL Connection* em tempo de execução e não ter que compilar o programa toda vez que mudo de computador.

No caso, criar um *Form* com as configurações do programa ou, antes do programa inicializar, solicitar o caminho do banco de dados.

Na imagem está destacado a propriedade que quero modificar.

[image: Em destaque a configuração que quero mudar em tempo de execução]

Tentei com este código:

```
   procedure TDMDados.ConexaoBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
   begin
       Conexao.Params:= 'Caminho do arquivo';
   end;
```

O problema é que, como eu já configurei essa conexão, esse parâmetro já esta definido.

Alguns parâmetros da conexão:

```
   DriverName=Firebird
   DriverUnit=Data.DBXFirebird
   DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver220.bpl
   DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=22.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
   MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXFirebirdMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxFirebirdDriver220.bpl
   MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXFirebirdMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxFirebirdDriver,Version=22.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
   LibraryName=dbxfb.dll
   LibraryNameOsx=libsqlfb.dylib
   VendorLib=fbclient.dll
   VendorLibWin64=fbclient.dll
   VendorLibOsx=/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Firebird
   Database=C:\Users\Johnny\Dropbox\1.MESTRADO\10.DISSERTAÇÃO\PROGRAMA DELPHI\Banco de dados\bd.fdb
   User_Name=sysdba
   Password=masterkey
   Role=RoleName
   [...]
```

Minha intenção é mudar este parâmetro da conexão em tempo de execução:

```
Database=C:\Users\Johnny\Dropbox\1.MESTRADO\10.DISSERTAÇÃO\PROGRAMA DELPHI\Banco de dados\bd.fdb
```

> "*- Eu ainda não consegui tentar fazer isso porque não sei como começar. Eu sei mudar os parâmetros da conexão antes de compilar*".

Comment: Então, o programa ele roda sem problemas. Eu gostaria de mudar a configuração da conexão do meu DB em tempo de execução.  Não sei se existe uma maneira de modificar os parâmetros da conexão antes de ela ser executada. Eu ainda nao consegui tentar fazer isso porque não sei como começar. Eu sei mudar os parametros da conexão antes de compilar....

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações na pergunta e coloquei os parametros da minha conexão. Eu nao encontrei nas bibliografias que li uma função nativa do delphi que modifique esse parâmetro. Como eu consigo modificar o parametro Database (conforme foto) direto pelo Object Inspector, achei que tivesse um comando do estilo " Conexao.Properties.Database ='caminho'. Entretanto não obtive sucesso nesses casos.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Pronto. Fiz o que pude. Logo alguém responde...

Comment: Obrigado. Ficou bem melhor =D Agora já tenho um pouco mais de base de como formatar as perguntas por aqui

Comment: Depois dá uma lida nos artigos da [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) que já vai ser uma base para entender o funcionamento, no geral, da comunidade. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depois de apanhar muito eis a solução que obtive, atendeu minha necessidade de maneira satisfatória.

Antes do programa criar o *Form1* é solicitado ao usuário selecionar o arquivo do banco de dados, logo o programa consegue obter o caminho do arquivo. Criei uma função(SelectBDpath) para obter o caminho do arquivo e na sequencia chamei a função e apliquei numa variável a qual será usada no meu *DataModule*.

```
function SelectBDpath() : string ;
var
    selectedFile: string;
    dlg: TOpenDialog;
begin
    selectedFile := '';
    dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
    try
        dlg.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;
        dlg.Filter :=   'Firebird DB Files|*.FDB';
        if dlg.Execute
            then
                SelectBDpath := dlg.FileName;
    finally
        dlg.Free;
   end;
end;
//Evento *OnCreate*
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        BDpath:=SelectBDpath();
        DMDados.Conexao.Open;
end;
```

Na sequencia a minha *DataModule* ,antes da conexão ocorrer,  "puxa" o caminho do arquivo (BDpath) do *Form1*(para tanto é necessário colocar *unit* correspondente no *uses* do *DataModule*) e aplica nos parâmetros da conexão do meu banco de dados, conforme código abaixo:

```
procedure TDMDados.ConexaoBeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        Conexao.Params.Values['Database']:= BDpath;
    end;
```

Desta maneira toda vez que executo o programa ele pedirá para selecionar o arquivo do meu banco de dados e aplicar nos parâmetros da conexão.